# Adding a boolean value to a search function

Tags: python, django, search, django-queryset, htmx

I have a multi-filter function that returns Clinic results based in 4 parameters. I want to add a 5th parameter which is a `BooleanField` (both in model and form).

I want the field to return the corresponding elements if `True`, but if `False`, return all the elements according to the other search parameters independently of this `BooleanField`.

```
if request.htmx:
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    ward = request.GET.get('ward')
    speciality = request.GET.get('speciality')
    english = request.GET.get('english')
    print(f'english: {english}')
    if all([len(name) == 0, len(city) == 0, len(ward) == 0, len(speciality) == 0]):
        qs = None
    else:
        qs = Clinic.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=name) &
                                   Q(city__icontains=city) &
                                   Q(ward__icontains=ward) &
                                   Q(speciality__icontains=speciality))
```

I tried to add the english variable to the queryset as

```
Q(english_support=english)
```

but without success. If I print out the result, it returns `None` if not checked, and `on` if checked. How can I add the condition that if `None`, return all the results according to the other `Q` parameters and if `True` just add it to the other conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain multiple `.filter()` methods, so apply the new boolean filter only when the respective form field is `True` (= its value is `on`, which is the default value for a checkbox).

```
if request.htmx:
    name = request.GET.get('name')
    city = request.GET.get('city')
    ward = request.GET.get('ward')
    speciality = request.GET.get('speciality')

    if all([len(name) == 0, len(city) == 0, len(ward) == 0, len(speciality) == 0]):
        qs = None
    else:
        qs = Clinic.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=name) &
                                   Q(city__icontains=city) &
                                   Q(ward__icontains=ward) &
                                   Q(speciality__icontains=speciality))

        if request.GET.get('english') == 'on':
            qs = qs.filter(english_support=True)
```